# STS - AXIS2 - Send soap message

Tags: grails, ssl, groovy, apache-axis

i am trying in grails / groovy in STS development enviroment (windows 7) trying to send SOAP request to server on address like :

https://a.b.c.d:7551/services/
(so it should be secured communication on specific port)

what i get is :

```
"CONNECT a.b.c.d:7551 HTTP/1.1"
"User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1[\r][\n]"
"Host: a.b.c.d:7551[\r][\n]"
"Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
"[\r][\n]"
"HTTP/1.1 502 Proxy Error ( The specified Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) port is not allowed. ISA Server is not configured to allow SSL requests from this port. Most Web browsers use port 443 for SSL requests.  )[\r][\n]"
"Via: 1.1 ISABA01[\r][\n]"
"Connection: close[\r][\n]"
"Proxy-Connection: close[\r][\n]"
"Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
"Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
"Content-Type: text/html[\r][\n]"
"Content-Length: 782   [\r][\n]"
"[\r][\n]"
```

with :

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 502 Error: Proxy Error ( The specified Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) port is not allowed. ISA Server is not configured to allow SSL requests from this port. Most Web browsers use port 443 for SSL requests.  )
```

"funny part" - when i try to send same request on same address with Cygwin - curl :

```
REQUEST='curl -k -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAction: GetService" -d @request -X POST https://a.b.c.d:7551/services/GetService'
eval RESPONSE=\$\($REQUEST\)
echo $RESPONSE
```

i got correct response

my network is using proxy (browser works ok, in curl example there was no special configuration, STS can connect to marketplace)

is there need to set something ?

thanks for help

Comment: Your proxy (MS ISA) seems to allow to proxy only these SSL requests which are directed to 443 port. Not 7551.

Comment: thank you for quick response ! so now i need to configure MS ISQ  (something like "extend ports for ssl to 7551")

Comment: Problem was solved. With command "grails add-proxy" there was added proxy (diferent than that one in system), after compile / deploy project was "ignoring" system proxy. It is really strange, that project is ignoring system proxy and "bigger" priority has proxy seted in grails.